# How to send data from Multiple Fragments to single activity on FAB button click

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, floating-action-button

> My problem is on clicking on `b4`(fab)only Fragment B data get in
>   SecondActivity.I want Both Fragment A and Fragment B Data collected
>   when clicking on`b4`Fab button available to both Fragment A and
>   Fragment B.
>
> Also in place of Fragment A data
>   `t4.setText(vres);`,`t5.setText(vres1);`,`t6.setText(vres2);` of
>   Second Activity get a value null.I don't understand why this is so?And
>   always getting data from Fragment B.I want both Fragment A and
>   Fragment B data to be fetched at SecondActivity when `b4`(fab)is
>   clicked.Thanks in advance.
>
> Fragment A

public class Fragment_nonveg extends Fragment {

```
    TextView t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10;
    CheckBox c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
    Button b1,b2,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12;
    ImageButton b3;
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10;
    String res,res1,res2,res3,res4,re,re1,re2,re3,re4;
    FloatingActionButton b4;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nonveg, null);
    }
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        b4 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent obj4 = new Intent(getActivity(), Bill.class);
                //obj4.putExtra("k", r1);

                int total = 0;
                String item = "", qty = "", amt = "";
                if (c1.isChecked() == true) {

                    item = item + c1.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    qty = qty + t2.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    amt = amt + t1.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t1.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (c2.isChecked() == true) {
                    item = item + c2.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    qty = qty + t4.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    amt = amt + t3.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t3.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (c3.isChecked() == true) {
                    item = item + c3.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    qty = qty + t6.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    amt = amt + t5.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t5.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (c4.isChecked() == true) {
                    item = item + c4.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    qty = qty + t8.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    amt = amt + t7.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t7.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);

                }
                if (c5.isChecked() == true) {
                    item = item + c5.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    qty = qty + t10.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    amt = amt + t9.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t9.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);

                }

                int T=total;
                obj4.putExtra("key", item);
                obj4.putExtra("key2", qty);
                obj4.putExtra("key3", amt);
                obj4.putExtra("key16", T);
                getActivity().startActivity(obj4);
            }
       });

    }
}
```

> Fragment B

```
public class Fragment_veg extends Fragment {


    FloatingActionButton b4;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_veg,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
b4 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do what you want
                Intent obj4 = new Intent(getActivity(), Bill.class);


                int total = 0;
                String vitem = "", vqty = "", vamt = "";
                if (vc1.isChecked() == true) {

                    vitem = vitem + vc1.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vqty = vqty + t2.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vamt = vamt + t1.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t1.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (vc2.isChecked() == true) {
                    vitem = vitem + vc2.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vqty = vqty + t4.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vamt = vamt + t3.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t3.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (vc3.isChecked() == true) {
                    vitem = vitem + vc3.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vqty = vqty + t6.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vamt = vamt + t5.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t5.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);
                }
                if (vc4.isChecked() == true) {
                    vitem = vitem + vc4.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vqty = vqty + t8.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vamt = vamt + t7.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t7.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);

                }
                if (vc5.isChecked() == true) {
                    vitem = vitem + vc5.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vqty = vqty + t10.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    vamt = vamt + t9.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String t = t9.getText().toString();
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(t);

                }
                int vT;
                vT = total;
                obj4.putExtra("vkey", vitem);
                obj4.putExtra("vkey2", vqty);
                obj4.putExtra("vkey3", vamt);
                obj4.putExtra("vkey16", vT);
                startActivity(obj4);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

> MainActivity

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nonveg,veg,snacks,desert,beverges;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageViewAdapter pageViewAdapter;
    public FloatingActionButton b4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        nonveg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nonveg);
        veg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.veg);
        snacks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.snacks);
        desert=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.desert);
        beverges=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.beverges);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        pageViewAdapter=new PageViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageViewAdapter);

        nonveg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        veg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });

        snacks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });

        desert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
            }
        });

        beverges.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                onChangeTab(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }
```

> SecondActivity

```
public class Bill extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t,t1,t2,t3,t16,t17,t4,t5,t6;
    Button b,b1;
    static   String res,res1,res2,/*res15,*/vres,vres1,vres2/*vres15*/;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bill);
        t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        t2 = findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        t3 = findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        t4 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        t5 = findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        t6 = findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        t16 = findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        t17 = findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        b = findViewById(R.id.button22);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.button23);
        Intent obj2 = getIntent();
        res = obj2.getStringExtra("key");
        res1 = obj2.getStringExtra("key2");
        res2 = obj2.getStringExtra("key3");
        int res15 = getIntent().getIntExtra("key16",0);
        vres = obj2.getStringExtra("vkey");
        vres1 = obj2.getStringExtra("vkey2");
        vres2 = obj2.getStringExtra("vkey3");
        int vres15 = getIntent().getIntExtra("vkey16",0);
        //vres15 = obj2.getStringExtra("vkey16");
        t1.setText(res);
        t2.setText(res1);
        t3.setText(res2);
        t4.setText(vres);
        t5.setText(vres1);
        t6.setText(vres2);
        t16.setText("Total Price:");
        int total2 = res15+vres15;
        t17.setText(String.valueOf(total2));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this question what is required is `sharedpreferences`.
>
> **Step 1:-** **In different Fragment** of fragment container in Activity implement like this:-

```
public class Fragment_class_name extends Fragment {
public static int totalp;
    public static String itemp, qtyp, amtp;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    private static Fragment_nonveg instance;
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        instance = this;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nonveg, null);
    }
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     //do your code
}
     public static Fragment_nonveg getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }
        public void yourfuncname(){//any calculative function you want to calculate or //pass data
sp=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("calis", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
editor.putString("key1",value1);
            editor.putString("key2",value2);
editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

> **Step 2:-** Then in Your **Activity** do like this:-

```
public class Activity_class_name extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageViewAdapter pageViewAdapter;
    public FloatingActionButton b4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        b4 = findViewById(R.id.fab);
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent obj4 = new Intent(Menu.this, Bill.class);
                Fragment_class_name.getInstance().yourfuncname();
                startActivity(obj4);
            }
        });
}
```

> **Step 3:-** Do this for all Fragments of fragment container

Answer (score 0):

For passing data between fragment and activity, you should declare interface then make a variable of that interface in fragment and on button click call one of the functions of interface and meanwhile in your activity implement those methods so by doing this you can pass any data from fragment to your activity by interface functions and parameters of those functions

```
 interface Test{
    void onSthHappend(String str);

} 
class fragment extends Fragment{
private Test interface;
 @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        interface= (Test ) context;
    }
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
interface.onSthHappend("hi");
            }
        });
}
clas activity Extends Activity implements Test{
@override onSthHappend(String str){
//do your stuff
}
}
```

Comment: by doing this, would it take multiple fragment data and pass it to single activity? As I have already gone through many of this type of solution on stackoverflow but they are for single fragments.

Comment: I have found what is required in this question here by processing the same coding `Fragment A` to all other fragments in following referred answer.please refer to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868402/how-to-access-local-variable-by-storing-it-to-class-variableglobal-in-java-and]